# How to print a receipt to a bluetooth thermal printer in iOS in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, printing, bluetooth, thermal-printer, ios-bluetooth

I am writing an App for a restaurant that needs to print receipts.

How to print to a bluetooth receipt thermal printer from an iOS App?

Just need to print simple text and maybe a logo.

I cannot find any current SDK. Just need support for iOS 8+

Comment: Based on the currently provided information nobody can answer your question right now. At first you need a basic understanding of how bluetooth communication between devices works. Just look for documentation on the CoreBluetooth framework provided by Apple. There were some sessions on the WWDC in the past years which are also a good point to start.

And when you finally understand the basics, you'll need to look for the documentation of your peripheral, i.e. the thermal printer. It will most likely consist of a custom set of commands which you can use to send and receive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK the solution is to use epson sample code which was just released about a month ago.

//  ePOS SDK Ver.2.4.0

It includes a library called libpos2.a

which you initialise with as Epos2Printer

Example: Epos2Printer *printer_; in objective-c

The source file is called "ePOS_SDK_Sample_iOS.zip"

Google it and you should fine it, make sure it is version 2 "ePOS2" is was released November 2016.

The discovery view controller allows to to select the printer and main view controller has the sample code you need to print to it.

Hope this helps!